# How to get current number values from different input box by jquery click funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input boxes in same page.

```
<input type="number" class="q"  />
<input type="number" class="q"  />
```

if i click on 1st input box it alerts the current value.But if i click on the 2nd input box it againt alerts the 1st input box value. How would i get the current value of that 2nd input box?

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$(".q").on("click", function() {
var orderQty = $('.q').val();
alert(orderQty)
});
```

Problem Solved: 
Working jQuery Code:

```
$(".q").on("click", function() {
var orderQty = $(this).val();
alert(orderQty)
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` instead.

Comment: Use `this.value`

Comment: you can also use $(".q").click(function(){}); as a shorthand for .on('click', function(){});

Comment: Its working now, thanks you all. 
Do i need to delete this post now????

Comment: no, mark one of the answers as the answer!

Comment: @Nate Didn't find any button to do this, i just joined...

Comment: gray/green check mark next to the answer you think answers your question best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of the `this` keyword inside of your event handler. Inside an event handler, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event.

The jQuery way:

```
var orderQty = $(this).val();
```

With plain JavaScript:

```
var orderQty = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.q').val()` will evaluate the FIRST one it finds in the jquery list. Use `$(this).val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(this).val()` should solve your problem:

```
$(".q").on("click", function() {
    var orderQty = $(this).val();
    alert(orderQty)
});
```

You can read more about `this` keyword [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).